# How many maps $A \overset{f}{\rightarrow} A$ satisfy $f \circ f = f$ with the given set $A=\{a, b, c\}$. A few related questions inside.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I am trying to calculate how many maps $A \overset{f}{\rightarrow} A$ satisfy $f \circ f = f$ with the given set $A=\{a, b, c\}$.

I would like to see the explicit mappings and learn how you constructed these mappings by hand, so I can apply these same techniques to future problems.

I'm self-studying this summer and have a few follow up questions, this will help solidify my understanding of the problems being asked.

**Question 1**:

What are the explicit mappings for this problem & how did you go about constructing them?

**Question 2:**

Is there a general procedure to calculate how many such mappings exist for any set A with an arbitrary number of elements?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597114/) might be of interested to you.

Comment: Some of the examples in your question do not satisfy the property $f \circ f = f$. For example, $f_2(a)=b$ but $f_2 \circ f_2(a) = f_2(b) = c \ne f_2(a)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher, thank you. Just noticed the same.

Comment: The condition on $f$ is that it fixes anything in its image, so there seem to be 10 possibilities for $f(a),f(b),f(c): a,a,a; a,a,c; a,b,a; a,b,b; a,b,c; a,c,c; b,b,b; b,b,c; c,b,c; c,c,c$.

Comment: @almagest, thank you. How did you calculate this?

Comment: @Max Just go through them by hand. If $f(a)\ne a$, say $f(a)=b$, then we must have $f(b)=b$, and we cannot have $f(c)=a$, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirement that $f\circ f=f$ is equivalent to the requirement that if $x\in f[A]$, then $f(x)=x$. That is, $f\upharpoonright\operatorname{ran}f$ must be the identity on $\operatorname{ran}f$, and any function whose restriction to its range is the identity will have the desired property.

Since it’s just as easy, I’m going to generalize your question. Let $A$ be a set of cardinality $n$; I’ll count the functions $f:A\to A$ such that $f\circ f=f$.

Let $B\subseteq A$, and let $m=|B|$; we’ll count the functions from $A$ to $B$ that are the identity on $B$. If $f$ is such a function, we know that $f(x)=x$ for each $x\in B$, but $f(x)$ can be any element of $B$ if $x\in A\setminus B$. Thus, in building such a function we get to make an $m$-way choice $n-m$ times, once for each $x\in A\setminus B$, so there are $m^{n-m}$ such functions.

For each $m$ there are $\binom{n}m$ subsets of $A$ of cardinality $m$, and each contributes $m^{n-m}$ functions with the desired property, so there are altogether

$$\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}mm^{n-m}\tag{1}$$

such functions. For $n=3$ this is

$$\binom30\cdot0^3+\binom31\cdot1^2+\binom32\cdot2^1+\binom33\cdot3^0=0+3+6+1=10\;.$$

Specifically, there are $3$ constant functions, $6$ functions with $2$-element ranges, and the identity function.

We can use $(1)$ to calculate the number of functions with the desired property for $n=0,1,2,3,4$; we get $1,1,3,10,41$, respectively. This turns out to be the start of the sequence [OEIS A000248](https://oeis.org/A000248). This is probably not obvious from the description at the head of the entry, but the third item in the COMMENTS section makes the identification easy:

> a(n) is the number of ways to select a set partition of {1,2,...,n} and then designate one element in each block (cell) of the partition.

If $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, a function $f:A\to A$ with the desired property does exactly that: the designated elements are the members of the range of $f$, and $f$ sends each element of a given block of the partition to the designated element of that block.

The FORMULA section of the entry gives a formulat equivalent to $(1)$, assorted generating functions, a recurrence (that isn’t especially nice), and an asymptotic estimate, but no closed form, so in all likelihood no closed form is known. In practice you would probably use $(1)$ to get the number of such functions.

Comment: @Max: (Sorry to have taken so long; it’s a busy weekend for me.) The [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}m$ is the number of $m$-element subsets of a set of $n$ things; numerically it’s $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$. Each of those subsets is the range of $m^{n-m}$ functions from $A$ to $A$ such that $f\circ f=f$. If $B$ is an $m$-element subset of $A$, such a function $f$ must satisfy $f(x)=x$ for each $x\in B$, so we know exactly what it does to $B$. If $x\in A\setminus B$, however, $f(x)$ can be any of the $m$ elements of $B$. Thus, in building ...

Comment: ... such an $f$, we have to choose one of the $m$ elements of $B$ for each of the $n-m$ elements of $A\setminus B$, and there are $m^{n-m}$ ways to do that. Putting the pieces together, we find that there are $\binom{n}mm^{n-m}$ such functions with $m$-element range, and we then sum over the possible sizes of the range of the function to get the total number of such functions. Does that help?

Comment: I was wondering if you could vet one other solution of mine when you time.  I have given the link.  Nobody has raised any concern but I wonder if you could let me know if it is correct.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772920/expected-value-and-sum-of-independent-variables/1774092#1774092

Comment: @Brian, no problem. I appreciate your time! I drew in a picture (albeit terribly) what I understand: https://imgur.com/Lx7p1fD -- This requires a bit of explaining. A, B are sets. |A|=n represents cardinality of A (n-elements), likewise for |B|=m. x_{b} represents all the m-elements in B and x_{a} represents all the elements in A not in B (not notated is x_{n} all elements in A).  Also what is shown is that every element in B has to map to the identity, which is notated as for all x_{b} in B, f(x_{b})= x_{b}. This is what I understood from what you stated. Following up in next comment my ?s.

Comment: @Brain, continuing with my questions. I do not understand what is meant by if x is the set A minus B (represented as x_{a} in my image), f(x_{a}) can be any of the m elements of B. I thought all elements in B mapped to themselves (identity mappings). So how can x_{a} (which is in A not in B) be an identity mapping from the set A\B to B? Aren't these two sets distinct? I have additional questions, but would like clarification on this first as I think my misunderstandings hinge on this confusion.

Comment: @Max: $A\setminus B$ is as you’ve drawn it: it’s the set of things that are in $A$ but not in $B$. If $f:A\to A$ has range $B$ and is such that $f\circ f=f$, then $f(x)$ must be $x$ for the elements of $A$ that are in $B$, $f(x)$ can be any member of $B$ if $x$ is in $A$ but not in $B$. Once we know the range of an $f$ with $f\circ f=f$, we know that $f$ is the identity function on that range, but on the other elements of $A$ it can take any value in the range (and definitely cannot be the identity function).

Comment: @Brian, thanks for the clarification. I am still slightly confused. How can f(x)=x be any member of B if x is in A but not B? From my understanding, f is the identity function, so it takes elements in the domain and maps them to the same elements in the range (so the domain/range should be the same set here). How can f take an element in A minus B and map it to an element in B, when by definition elements in A minus B excludes elements from B? It seems like A\B is distinct from B and you can't map an element from A\B to its identity in B, because A\B are exactly the elements not in B.

Comment: @Max: If $x\in A\setminus B$, then $f(x)$ clearly is *not* equal to $x$: $B$ is the range of $x$, so by definition $f(x)\in B$ for *every* $x\in A$. This means that it’s impossible for $f(x)$ to be equal to $x$ when $x\notin B$. Go back to your original small example. If $B=\{a,b\}$, then we have to have $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$ in order for $f\circ f$ to equal $f$, but $f(c)$ can be either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: @Brian, I think I finally understand what this means. For example A={a,b,c}, B={a,b}. |A|=3,|B|=2. (1) is calculating the # of fns from A to B that are the identity on B, or f(x)=x for each x in B. f(x) can be any element of B if x in A\B = {c} (in this example). So we get to make 3-way choice 1-time for each x in A\B = {c} and there are 3 such functions. Namely: f(a)=a, f(b)=a, f(c)=c; f(a)=b,f(b)=b, f(c)=c; f(a)=c, f(b)=c, f(c)=c;. Is this correct?

Comment: @Brian, What does 3-way choice, 1-time actually mean in this example? Does it mean there are 3 functions that map 1 identity element to B, where the other 2 are constant?

Comment: @Max: No, that’s not right. There are only two functions $f:A\to A$ such that $f[A]=\{a,b\}$ and $f\circ f=f$: one is $f(a)=a,f(b)=b,f(c)=a$, and the other is $f(a)=a,f(b)=b,f(c)=b$. There is just $|A\setminus B|=1$ member of $A$ whose value under such a function is not completely determined by the fact that $f[A]=\{a,b\}$, and member is $c$. All three of your functions have the property that $f\circ f=f$, but the range of the first is $\{a,c\}$, that of the second is $\{b,c\}$, and that of the third is $\{c\}$; none of them has range $B=\{a,b\}$.

Comment: @Brian, thanks for the correction.  I believe I now understand it, can you verify? http://pastebin.com/Y0CB5wV2

Comment: @Max: You’re welcome. Yes, that looks good.

Comment: The formulation in terms of partitions would seem to indicate exponential generating functions should be useful - I'm getting $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n = e^{x e^x}$.  (Then, computing a Taylor series expansion with a CAS and extracting the $x^3$ coefficient does seem to match the answer of 10.)

Answer (score 1):

The only bijective map that satisfies the condition is the identity. So the other maps are not surjective.

Suppose the image of $f$ is $\{a,b\}$. Then $a=f(x)$ for some $x$ and so $f(a)=f(f(x))=f(x)=a$; similarly $f(b)=b$. Therefore we're left with $f(c)=a$ or $f(c)=b$. This gives two maps.

Therefore we have $2\cdot 3$ maps having their image with cardinality $2$.

Suppose the image of $f$ is $\{a\}$. Then $f(a)=a$ as before; moreover, the restriction on the image forces $f(b)=a$ and $f(c)=a$. Thus only one map exists.

Therefore we have $1\cdot 3$ maps having their image with cardinality $1$.

In total, $1+6+3=10$ maps satisfy the condition.